# Showing jQuery progress bar during function execution

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a button click function, which accomplished a series of task. I want to show and update a progressbar upon completion of each task lets say 25%, 50% and likewise, I am using jQuery progress bar to achieve this and using 4 hidden fields to store the different values but the progress bar doesnot grow as the function goes on it directly show 100% complete the code sample is as follows

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="btnExecute" OnClientClick="return timeout_init();" OnClick="btnExecute_Click" />
```

codebehind: setting different hiddenfield values

```
protected void btnExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Ist level task complete
        hfProgressValue.Value = "25";
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        //IInd level task completion
        ProgressValue1.Value = "50";
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        //3rd level task 
        prg2.Value = "75";
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        //4th level task
        hfprg3.Value = "100";
    }
```

javascript

```
function timeout_init() {

            var progressBarVal = $("input[id$='hfProgressValue']").val();
            var progressBarVal1 = $("input[id$='ProgressValue1']").val();
            var progressBarVal2 = $("input[id$='prg2']").val();
            var progressBarVal3 = $("input[id$='hfprg3']").val();

            if (progressBarVal != "") {
                $("#progressbar").progressbar({
                    value: parseInt(progressBarVal)
                });
            }
            if (progressBarVal1 != "") {
                $("#progressbar").progressbar({
                    value: parseInt(progressBarVal1)
                });
            }
            if (progressBarVal2 != "") {
                $("#progressbar").progressbar({
                    value: parseInt(progressBarVal2)
                });
            }
            if (progressBarVal3 != "") {
                $("#progressbar").progressbar({
                    value: parseInt(progressBarVal3)
                });
            }
            setTimeout('timeout_init()', 0);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use ajax to

1. submit the original request
2. poll the server for progress updates.

the progress will need to be stored outside of a request so that each request can access the progress.

Comment: this is within a usercontrol so i cannot use page methods, also the button is inside update panel

Comment: you'll loose the update panel, but other than that the server side rendering is indifferent. all the client needs are the proper urls. these urls are then mapped to the appropriate handlers on the server. yes, you will be departing the webforms model in favor of a truer HTTP model, but asp.net handles HTTP very well.